# How Can I Post inpputed Array Data in PHP?

Tags: php

I've already tried this stuff

`$item=$_POST($val['item_id'])`

And

```
$item=$_POST[$val['item_id']]
```

Any Idea on how to Post my inputted data ?

Comment: in each of youe question the input are really less. Please describe your question with more amount of data (like form code and where you are facing problem). Also don't go blindly asking question. Do some R&D

Comment: noted, will reconstruct my question in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` isn't a function, it is a special PHP array that reflects the data submitted from a form. So, the second line you got there can work only if the `$val['item_id']` has a valid post name key. You should always first check if that key actually exists in the `$_POST` data array by using `isset` function like this:

```
if (isset($_POST[$val['item_id']]) {
    $item = $_POST[$val['item_id']];
}
```

To debug and see all `$_POST` data, use this code:

```
<pre><?php
print_r($_POST);
?></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) **form.html**

Make sure your form uses POST method.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
  <input name="say" value="Hi">
  <input name="to" value="Mom">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

2) **submit.php**

```
var_export($_POST);
```

Will result in:

```
array (
  'say' => 'Hi',
  'to' => 'Mom',
)
```

`$_POST` is not a function, but an array superglobal, which means you can access submitted data thus:

`print $_POST['field_name']`

Comment: No problem na. `var_export` is pretty handy, as it returns valid PHP code (unlike `var_dump`)